# phpMyAdmin executes queries faster than normal PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos8

I have an SQL query:

```
SELECT country_code FROM GeoIP WHERE 3111478102>=ip_from AND 3111478102<=ip_to;
```

I tried to execute the same query in both phpMyAdmin and a normal php script, and here is the result:

**phpMyAdmin**

[image]

**PHP Script**

[image]

As you can see that the query took only 0.8s to be fully executed in phpMyAdmin. Whereas it took 4.5s in the normal PHP Script!

The php script code:

```
<?php
    // ob_start();
    // error_reporting(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    header_remove("X-Powered-By");
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 13824000);
    session_set_cookie_params(13824000);
    session_start();
    include_once './config.php';
    // include_once './functions/mainClass.php';

    $beforeMicro = microtime(true);
    $res = $conn->query("SELECT country_code FROM GeoIP WHERE 3111478102>=ip_from AND 3111478102<=ip_to");
    if ($res->rowCount() > 0){
        $sen = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $country_code = $sen->country_code;
        print_r([$country_code]);
    }
    $afterMicro = microtime(true);
    echo 'time:'.round(($afterMicro-$beforeMicro)*1000);
?>
```

In the meantime, I am setting up a new web server and I use the following:

```
CentOS 8
Apache 2.4.46
PHP 7.2.24
```

Please note: The table I'm searching in (GeoIP) contains over 39 minion record. But I think that this is not the problem because that the same query is ran faster in the same server. I also tried to upload the same database and the PHP script to another a Shared Hosting account (not my own server), and it worked and was executing the query in just 1.6s from the php script.

Comment: Try `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE country_code...`. Is PMA on the same server as the code you're running? Are they on the same server as MySQL?

Comment: @user3783243 I tried to execute the same php script without the `$conn->query()` and the lines related to it. The result was `time: 0`. I also tried to execute the same query in phpMyAdmin without letting it to cache and it's the same (time: 0.7 or time: 0.8).

Comment: @rjdown I tried `SQL_NO_CACHE` and the execution time was the same (0.7s or 0.8s). Both the PHP script and PMA are running in the same server and using the same MySQL.

Comment: @rjdown: SQL_NO_CACHE is deprecated for some time now, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584596/mysql-8-warning-sql-no-cache-is-deprecated/66491613#66491613

Comment: @user3783243, Yes, it's the same (it took over 4s to be executed).

Comment: @user3783243, Please check out the following screenshot: https://prnt.sc/10kgugh

Comment: Thanks, so it is query and not fetch return etc.

Comment: @user3783243, I tried to do the same scenario on another server (Hostgator). And the result was `Time: 0.792s`.

Comment: Connecting to same DB or replicated system there?

Comment: @user3783243, I exported the same database and I uploaded the same php script.

Comment: Could you try connecting to that db with this script or vice versa?

Comment: @user3783243, The following screenshot contains the result of a request of my server to the hostgator db: https://prnt.sc/10khvj8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a helpful thread for your question:
[Why would phpmyadmin be significantly faster than the mysql command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944969/why-would-phpmyadmin-be-significantly-faster-than-the-mysql-command-line)

> Front-end tools like phpMyAdmin often staple on a LIMIT clause in order to paginate results and not crash your browser or app on large tables. A query that might return millions of records, and in so doing take a lot of time, will run faster if more constrained.
>
> It's not really fair to compare a limited query versus a complete one, the retrieval time is going to be significantly different. Check that both tools are fetching all records.

Comment: The problem is that the PHP Script is executing SQL queries so slow. The problem is not why PMA is too fast! Because, simply the same scenario is done in only 1.5s on another server.

Comment: @GhadeerR.Majeed _..The problem is not why PMA is too fast! ..._ But the title of your question is in fact "phpMyAdmin executes queries faster than normal PHP script"

Comment: @B001ᛦ, Exactly, which means that there's a problem in PHP/Apache/MySQL that should be fixed. Not decreasing the speed of phpMyAdmin ^^